# Programming simple GUI applications? A couple considerations

Tags: c, linux, bash

I am wanting to start programming some simple applications that I can use as tools and such. I am hoping these applications will allow me to simplify certain terminal processes I use often. They interact with my local files lots as well as other applications (db2 for example). I have started learning C a little bit for this.

I thought I would use C with embedded bash commands. I was wondering if that was the best/most common method of programming these applications? Is there a better way of doing this? Also, I will need to be able to display the terminal output. Will this be possible? My only issue with this method is that it is not very transferable to non Linux operation system.

Any insight or a push in the general direction would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You perhaps should consider learning python or Ocaml and use that to code your simple GUI scripts.

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch Is this a joke about Ocaml? Is it a _simple_ or _common_ method as topic author asked?

Comment: No, several people are using Ocaml with Lablgtk with ease for such purposes.

Comment: However, with any language, I would find that learn programming by coding GUI application is not the best way. To learn programming, start by coding simple command line apps. GUI apps are complex, because they involve an event loop out of your control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want cross-platform, consider [Qt](http://qt-project.org/) or [WxWidgets](http://www.wxwidgets.org/). I'd go with Qt, but that is only because I don't know WxWidgets ;)

If you want simple things quickly, use Qt with [PyQt](http://wiki.python.org/moin/PyQt) or [PySide](http://qt-project.org/wiki/PySide) (also see [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1297660/pyside-vs-pyqt)). WxWidgets has Python bindings too, according to it's webpage. Learning Python is generally fun, useful, and an order of magnitude faster and easier than learning C++.

Forget C for GUI programming, GUIs are inherently object-based, and much easier to work with on languages which support objects naturally.

For child process handling, a quick search for Python and Qt found [this example at www.qtforum.org](http://www.qtforum.org/article/32172/qprocess-how-to-run-multiple-processes-in-a-loop.html?s=5b02b50266d444eba7c2f28adc2192efb483bea5#post104277).

Comment: well i do have some experience in coding. but mostly logical operations and just scripting rather than applications.
I have experience in python, scheme, a little and c++
Lots with VBA


I read about Qt and GTK, But that actually isnt quite what i was hoping to learn. 

My question is which library should i use to actually interact with my files and other applciations? does Qt or GTK provide methods for getting the terminal output of another program? 


for example, if i decided to create a gui for db2, since i normally run db2 with terminal commands, does GTK provide that?

Comment: At least Qt has QProcess, which provides event-based interaction with child process (giving separate Qt signals for stderr, stdout output from the child process).

Comment: Added link to a Python Qt example, which executes `uname` from GUI.

Comment: thanks everyone! this looks like enough for me to get a good start!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the mentioned toolkits such as **PyQt** and **wxPython**, standard python itself comes with a cross platform GUI kit called **Tkinter**.

Also if you're on Linux you can try(for C) **Gtk**.

For C++ I would suggest **Qt** or **wxWidgets**

Or try Java if you don't mind installing a heavy-weight virtual machine. It comes with **Swing**.

Apart from all these **Toolkits** for Graphical User Interface, interfacing a graphical user program with command line program is .. well .. nevermind. You will need to open pipes to the subprocess(the command line process), read output from it, write into the subprocess's input stream, and show appropriate message to the user.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using Qt over wxWidgets.  For portability to Linux, Qt from my experiences works better.  I've had a few projects work great on mac/windows, but seg fault on linux due to nuances in running a particular wxWidget build.  Using Qt also allows you to use plenty of efficient and fast data structures specific to Qt.